# Let $U$ be a open connected subset of a space $X$, then show that $U$ is a component of $X\smallsetminus \partial U$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

**Q.** Let $U$ be a open connected subset of a space $X$, then show that $U$ is a component of $X\smallsetminus \partial U$.

**My attempt:**
I want to prove that any proper superset $V(\subseteq X\smallsetminus \partial U)$ of $U$ is disconnected. I show $V$ is disconnected by showing $U$ is a proper nonempty clopen subset of $V$. Only required thing to prove is $U$ is closed in $V$. Now $U$ is open, so any the limit point of $U$, which is outside $U$, is in $\partial U$. But $V\subseteq X\smallsetminus \partial U$ gives $V$ does not contain any limit point of $U$,which is outside the $U$. Thus, $U$ is closed in $V$.

Is this argument flawless? Or, is there any other way to prove? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is good. I wouldn't talk about limit points, though, since it seems unnecessary to me: it's clearer to just say that $U\cup \partial U$ is closed in $X$, and $U=(U\cup \partial U)\cap V$, and hence $U$ is closed in $V$. but maybe it's a matter of taste...